# Passing objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pass an object in javascript. But i am getting an error `javascript:callbackCredits(1,dotsContainer_credits); is undefined`

My code is as follows:

```
var dotSlideCredits = {
    show : 3,                       
    width : 430,  
    functionName : "callbackCredits",       
    title: "title",
    itemId: "#s_credit"
}

var test = {
     data[]
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   dynamicList(dotSlideCredits);
}

 function dynamicList(dotSlide){
            var divItems = "dotsContainer_"+dotSlide.title;
        test.data.push({title: dotSlide.title+[i], callBack:  "javascript:"+dotSlide.functionName+"("+i+","+divItems+");"});
 }


 function callbackCredits(current, container){
    var prev = $("#previousCredit").val();
    slideShow(current, prev, container);       
    $("#previousCredit").attr("value", current);
 }
```

Comment: looking at the code up there i cant find where you set dotSlide.functionName ... that could be a problem ;)

Comment: also i am assuming that test.data is a valid array and declared

Comment: dotSlide.functionName is present on my code.. I just forgot to put it above... See my revision

Comment: callBack:  "javascript:"+dotSlide.functionName+"("+i+","+divItems+");"})     is my code because i have another code that inserts this callback in an <a href>

Comment: see my solution and instead of adding the whole function to your object you could add something like that : function(x,y){ callBackCredits(x,y);} // ... ( make sure to rename the vars ;) ) then leave the function in your code so your href still works :) ... ill edit my solution too :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5806/discussion-between-lilmonkey-and-newbie)

Comment: You need to show more code, especially the part that tries to do something with the callback function. The part of your code shown won't work at all because your `dotSlideCredits` object doesn't have a `title` property, and its `functionName` is an actual reference to the function but you use it as if it was a string with the name. `i` isn't defined. `test` is declared with invalid syntax. Also, what are you trying to do with `dotSlide.title+[i]`? This would create a new array with one element, `i`, and then add it to a title which is presumably a string - this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: yes. dotSlide.title+[i] should be a string... i just want to pass a string value of the title... :(

Comment: for example title1 title2 title3... etc

Comment: in my actual code i have the title and the function name.. i just forgot to include it above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i would do probably is something like that :

```
var dotSlideCredits = { 
    show : 3,                        
    width : 430,                         
    itemId: "#s_credit",
    functionName: function(current, container){
      callbackCredits(current,container);
    }
}
```

function callbackCredits(current, container) {
  var prev = $("#previousCredit").val();
  slideShow(current, prev, container);
  $("#previousCredit").attr("value", current); 
}

and then simply call `dotSlide.functionName(i,divItems);`

(not tested bout should be something close to that)

Comment: i am guessing the problem is the string around "javascript: .... " the code is expecting a function and is getting a string but i am not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the callBack property isn't a function? It probably should be

E.g.:

```
test.data.push({
    title: dotSlide.title+[i], 
    callBack: function () {
        dotSlide.functionName(i,divItems);
    }
});
```

does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty descriptive. You've added a bogus `"javascript:"` prefix to your function name. Remove it.